# Specifying CSS size in `cm` does not produce correct size

Tags: css

I have a small touchscreen display that we are serving up HTML pages to. The physical dimensions of the LCD is 4.624cm wide by 3.508cm high. Creating a `div` with a `width` & `height` set appropriately creates a *much* smaller rectangle on the display.

Why would `cm` not translate to the real dimensions on the screen? What adjustment do I need to make so I can work in centimeters, instead of pixels?

Comment: But according to w3 you should not use the cm http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html

Comment: Why not use `vh` and `vw` for *viewport* width and height to set it to the screen's dimensions exactly or even percentage? `width:100vw` and `height:100vh` Or `height:100%` and `width:100%`?

Comment: @ctwheels - I will also need to specify smaller object sizes - 5cm, 7cm, etc. - within the main view. The "full screen" example is simply the first problem I'm trying to fix.

Comment: You're better off using percentage then. Use media queries if you have multiple screen dimensions `@media`. Another suggestion is to simply convert cm to px, but that should be a **last** resort

Comment: @ctwheels - I only have to worry about 1 screen type (we control the hardware). Why do you suggest converting cm-to-px be a last resort?

Comment: For multiple devices, it should be last resort, but since you are making it for one device, you can use px so long as you know the resolution.

Comment: What I would do in your case is figure out how many px per cm exist, and then base your sizing off of that measurement. So for example, one cm being 37.8 pixels, your box needing to be 5cm would be 189px (using this conversion calculator I randomly found: http://www.unitconversion.org/typography/centimeters-to-pixels-y-conversion.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As w3c docs states:

> The so-called absolute units (cm, mm, in, pt and pc) mean the same in CSS as everywhere else, but only if your output device has a high enough resolution. On a laser printer, 1cm should be exactly 1 centimeter. But on low-resolution devices, such as computer screens, CSS doesn't require that. And indeed, the result tends to be different from one device to another and from one CSS implementation to another.

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html#units

Comment: This makes me sad. I'm a sad monkey now! :( But with SCSS and the magic of maths, (screen dpi) x (screen size) = (number of pixels) - I could then do a little more number crunching to get a cm-to-px conversion, yes?

Comment: hello from the future. an idea is: just write your sizes in css centimeters, then with the help of `transform: scale(1.1)` or something similar you can force the cm to equal what you think it should